# Behaviour of HTTPSession and Spring session scoped beans

Tags: spring, session, scope, session-timeout

I'm having an issue regarding HTTPSession and Spring beans that I quite don't understand. In web.xml I've set the session timeout to 1 minute:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

On each Ajax request I make I check whether the session is or not valid:

```
if(request.getSession(false) == null)
            System.out.println("Session Invalid");
```

But it looks like it's still valid after the minute has passed (it is not null).

Then something happens that confuses me. I have several beans with this annotation:

```
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

The first minute, they work fine, the same instance of the bean is always injected and I can store some info and recover it later, but if I wait one minute and then I send another request, then a different instance of the bean is injected and the info I had is lost.

I believe what's happening is that since the session should've expired, the bean injected is different, but then why is *request.getSession(false)* not null and *request.getSession(false).isValid()* is **true**?